# Perform end-to-end automated testing of OIDC integration with Google

Tags: google-oauth, single-sign-on, openid-connect

My team is integrating "Login with Google" into our web SSO service (built on top of ForgeRock OpenAM).  We need the ability to programmatically verify that the integration is configured correctly as part of our CI/CD post-deployment testing.

We're running into problems.  There is client-side JavaScript that must be executed in order for the call sequence to proceed successfully, so we can't automate without the browser.  And if we try to automate the login using Selenium, then anti-bot measures get thrown up on the Google login screen.

We can't be the only team on the planet that integrates with Google that wants to do at least minimal automated end-to-end testing in support of CI/CD.  So there must be a solution.  Does anyone know what it is?